# Deleting scripts interfering with each other in <head> tag

Tags: jquery, sed

I have a script that is prevented from functioning due to the other scripts in the  tag of most of the webpages that I saved on my disk (about 5). It seems the only way the script can function is if I manually delete the contents of the  tag (effectively taking out the scripts), inserting the custom script, saving the file, and then running it. Is there a way I could delete all the contents of the  tag before they are loaded, or if I could delete the contents, save the page, and reload it with the custom script?

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">'want to remove this</script>
     <script type="text/javascript">'want to remove this also</script>
      <script type="text/javascript">'want this to run after deleting scripts</script>
      <title>'want to keep this'</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: why dont you just change the pages?

Comment: I want to do this for alot of pages eventually ...it would be quite tedious to them one by one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery.
You need to write a simple sed/awk script to remove the tags that you want.
Provide more details on what you want to remove and also what OS you're using.
Edit :
On a linux system something like this would do the trick

```
sed 's/<script type="text/javascript">What you want removed</script>//'
```